# How to uninstall Python packages installed globally on Mac?

Tags: python, macos

While writing Python code in PyCharm on Mac I installed some Python Packages not in the virtual Environment but globally. How can I check those installed Packages and delete them?

Comment: `sudo pip uninstall packagename` should do the trick, assuming you installed it with `sudo pip install packagename`

Answer (score 1):

To check whether a package is installed, run

```
pip freeze
```

to get a list of all packages, then search for the package.

To uninstall a package, run

```
pip uninstall [package name]
```

Of course you have to run these commands globally (and not inside your virtual environment)

I wish you much luck

Comment: Open the terminal in your OS and make sure you‘re not inside the folder of the virtual environment, that should work

Comment: sorry for asking so much but I am opening Terminal entering python3 and then typing the commands but I get a SyntaxError ` pip uninstall py2app
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: You don‘t need to run python, simply type in into the terminal.

Comment: then I get the error zsh: command not found: pip

Comment: Then try writing „pip3“ instead of „pip“

Comment: ok that seems to work except it doesn't show me any installed packages. Can it be because I did not install them using 'sudo pip install packagename' . PyCharm just showed me an error and installed them for me

Comment: Indeed, that‘s a bit odd; maybe you find something using „pip3 list“ or try „sudo pip3 list“. Does the uninstallation of py2app not work either?

Comment: uninstalling py2app returns: 'warning: Skipping py2app as it is not installed.'

Comment: Even if you run as „sudo“?

Comment: sudo pip3 list gives me the current version of pip and setuptools

Comment: pip3 uninstall py2app
WARNING: The directory '/Users/omarkilzy/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned or is not writable by the current user. The cache has been disabled. Check the permissions and owner of that directory.

Comment: If executing pip with sudo, you should use sudo's -H flag.
WARNING: Skipping py2app as it is not installed.
WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv

Comment: Could you try to run the „deactivate“ command again to make sure the virtual environment is really deactivated?

Comment: sorry but what's the "deactivate command"

Comment: Just „deactivate“ in the terminal. This schould deactivate the virtual environment and let everything go back to normal.

Comment: Okay, then you‘re outside of the virtual environment and py2app has probably not been installed globally on your machine. That‘s unfortunately the only way I can explain that… I hope I could help you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pip freeze` command to get all your globally installed packages and delete them